# Node JS : use mongodb on imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, import, module

I have a app.js that connect to a mongodb database an display it with express.My app.js is starting to be quite long. So I'm trying to do "modular design". I need to do a "timer.js" that will do some stuff in my mongodb with a timer.

I want to import this function from "checking.js" but this file require mongodb, some constant from DOTENV etc. so I need a import/export relation between them. How to do it ?

**App.js (main file)**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const POWER = process.env.POWER;

var mongoDb = require('mongodb');

var mongoClient = mongoDb.MongoClient;

const serverUrl = process.env.ENV_SERVEUR_MONGO_URL;

const useDB = process.env.ENV_MONGO_DATABASE;

app.get('/top', function (req, res) {
    var resultArray = [];

mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, function (err, client) {
        var db = client.db(useDB);
        if (err) throw err;
        var cursor = db.collection('top').find().sort({ _id: -1 });
        cursor.forEach(function (doc, err) {
            resultArray.push(doc);
        }, function () {
            client.close();
            res.render('pages/top', { items: resultArray })
        });
    });
});

var checking = require('./checking')
```

**Checking.js**

````
function checkingdatabase() {
    
// ERROR require mongodb, variable undefined etc.
    mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, function (err, client) {
        var db = client.db(useDB);
        if (err) throw err;
        //do stuff
    });
}

setInterval(checkingActiveOffer, 5000);

module.exports = Object.assign({ checkingdatabase })```
````

Comment: You have to write the required import statements in checking.js so that it can work correctly and compile without giving you any errors.

Answer (score 0):

create DB.js file and share MongoDB connection

```
     mongoose.connect(process.env.ENV_SERVEUR_MONGO_URL;, { useFindAndModify: false, useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(function (res) {
        
        console.log('Succeeded connected to: ' + process.env.ENV_SERVEUR_MONGO_URL;);
        exports.isReady = true;
        exports.connection = res;
        exports.con = res.connection
    })
```

Checking.js

```
   var db = require('./DB')
   app.get('/top', function (req, res) {
   db.con.collection('top').find().sort({_id:-1}).toArray()
   .then(r=>{
      res.render('pages/top', { items: resultArray })
    })
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two different ways:

1 - You pass the values you need as a prop to Checking function. So this way you would pass your envs and your mongo client when you invoke Checking function. **Not advisable**

2 - You can, and should, declare the things you need inside the Checking file. Your envs and mongoClient can just be required there, and it will make your code cleaner.

Take a look at [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-gagarin-4g4ov?file=/src/index.js) and see if that suits your use case.